# Moving redux-form formValueSelector to HOC

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to move my connected redux-from selector to my HOC which handles mapState and mapDispatch.

Currently my component looks like this...

```
class MainForm extends React.Component {

render() { ... }

}

let MainReduxForm = reduxForm({
  form: "mainForm", 
})(MainForm);

const selector = formValueSelector('mainForm')
MainReduxForm = connect(state => {
  const isUsed = selector(state, 'isUsed');
  const location = selector(state, 'location');

  return {
    isUsed,
    location,
  };
  },
)(MainReduxForm);

export default MainReduxForm;
```

and HOC looks like this...

```
const mapState = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {

  };
};



const mapDispatch = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
    return {
      onOrderChange: order => dispatch({type: 'FETCH_ORDER', order: order}),

    }
}

export const MainFormContainer = connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(MainReduxForm);
```

How do I move the connect/formValueSelector piece of the functionality to the HOC?

I'm not sure where exactly it should live in HOC, but I'm trying to seperate concerns if possible and would love to colocate the functional piece with some other SAGA pieces that are being called from within mapDispatch.